# Docker Compose Link Containers for Phpunit with Wordpress, MySQL

Tags: wordpress, unit-testing, docker-compose

I would like to use a docker-compose app to run unit tests on a wordpress plugin.

Following (mostly) [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@tatemz/using-wp-cli-with-docker-21b0ab9fab79#.ymboziyr0) I have created four containers:

```
my-wpdb:
  image: mariadb
  ports:
    - "8081:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dockerpass

my-wp:
  image: wordpress
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  links:
    - my-wpdb:mysql
  environment:
    WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: dockerpass

my-wpcli:
  image: tatemz/wp-cli
  volumes_from:
    - my-wp
  links:
    - my-wpdb:mysql
  entrypoint: wp  
  command: "--info"

my-phpunit:
  image: phpunit/phpunit
  volumes_from:
    - my-wp
  links:
    - my-wpdb
```

This [tutorial](https://pippinsplugins.com/unit-tests-wordpress-plugins-setting-up-testing-suite/) got me as far as creating the phpunit files (xml, tests, bin, .travis), with the exception that I had to install subversion manually:

```
docker exec wp_my-wp_1 apt-get update 
docker exec wp_my-wp_1 apt-get install -y wget git curl zip vim
docker exec wp_my-wp_1 apt-get install -y apache2 subversion libapache2-svn libsvn-perl
```

And run the last part of `bin/install-wp-tests.sh` manually in the database container:

`docker exec wp_my-wpdb_1 mysqladmin create wordpress_test --user=root --password=dockerpass --host=localhost --protocol=tcp`

I can run phpunit: `docker-compose run --rm my-wp phpunit --help`.

I can specify the config xml file:

`docker-compose run --rm my-wp phpunit --configuration /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/phpunit.xml.dist`

However, the test wordpress installation is installed in the `my-wp` container's `/tmp` directory: `/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/functions.php`

I think I have to link the `my-phpunit` containers `/tmp` to the one in `my-wp`?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer my question, but as a solution to the problem, there is a github repo for a Docker Image that provides the wanted features: https://github.com/chriszarate/docker-wordpress as well as a wrapper you can invoke it through: https://github.com/chriszarate/docker-wordpress-vip

I wonder if for the initial set-up (noted in the question), it might make more sense to add Phpunit to the Wordpress container, rather than making a separate container for it.